# what's the difference between findViewById<T>() and findViewById() as T?

Tags: android

when I try this code, I can get the result right.

```
val layout: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.custom_toast_layout))
```

But when I try this casting code, I get the null error.

```
val layout: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout)) as ViewGroup
```

So I guess

*If I use casting code*

findViewById method find according to this generic T at first. And if there is no id about T, it returns null, then start casting, and I get the null.

*If I use explicit code*

findViewById method find according to this generic T at first. And there is an id I want, it returns view, and I get the view.

This is my guess. I want to know the reason about this happening exactly.

Comment: Clearly the <T> one is generic and lets you define return type. the second one that uses `as T` returns Object (Any) an you need to cast it yourself. use `as?` to avoid casting exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LayoutInflaters `inflate` Methode returns a `View`.

> public View inflate (int resource, ViewGroup root)

The second parameter is a ViewGroup.
You are casting the return value of inflate (`View`) to `ViewGroup`.

Your cast needs to be made for the second parameter instead:

`val layout: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout) as ViewGroup)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `val layout: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout)) as ViewGroup`

It should be `val layout: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast, findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout) as ViewGroup)`

Issues here is, you are casting the hole `inflater.inflate()` instead the return value of `findViewById()`